# Common Mistakes in Laravel Form

Tags: forms, laravel

There are some common mistakes we do in `laravel` form even though we know about that mistakes. When we know about why mistakes are encountered, We can easily realize how silly were the mistakes. I've added some mistakes are here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't actually asking a question.

Comment: @fubar I've shared what I know about some silly mistakes in form, If other people here know some other mistakes, it will be good have some good answers over here.

Comment: I understand that, and agree it could be of benefit. I just don't think posting a question with _tips_ is the best way to share that information.

Comment: I'm sorry for that and Thanks @fubar

Comment: Do a blog post instead. (use medium.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list of some common mistakes we do in laravel form.

**1. CSRF token field**

We need to add hidden csrf token field in every laravel form to protect  application from cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks. we can use `csrf_field` to generate hidden csrf token field as follows.

```
 <form method="POST" action="/create">

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    ...

 </form>
```

When we see error **TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line ...** , then we just remember the mistake we have made.

**2. File Upload**

When you make a **POST** request, you have to encode the data that forms the body of the request in some way.

When you are writing client-side code, all you need to know is use **multipart/form-data** when your form includes any  elements.

During file upload with form, sometime we forgot to add **enctype="multipart/form-data"** so that just name of the file is passed with `form-request` and no file is uploaded. So, What we need to do is

```
<form method="POST" action="/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="file" name="upload">

    ....

</form>
```

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` means that no characters will be encoded. that is why this type is used while uploading files to server.

So, **multipart/form-data** is used when a form requires binary data, like the contents of a file, to be uploaded.

**3. Array input fields**

When we work with array of input fields in the form, some time we forgot about array input definition and use array input like

```
<input name="data">
....
<input name="data">
```

As all we know this will send only one value even there are number of input field. So, We need to define input fields as

```
<input name="data[]">
....
<input name="data[]">
```

And, another mistake with array is validation at server side like this.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'data' => 'required|alpha_num'
], $messages = [

]
```

This validation will always fails since `data` is of array so it will not be **alpha-numeric**. So, we can validate like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'data' => 'required',
    'data.*' => 'required|alpha_num'
], $messages = [

]
```

After this we can easily access `data[]` like:

```
foreach($request->data as $d){

    // save data with loop

}
```